# Ionic 2 problems with samsung s5 mini android 6.0.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, s5

I'm using ionic 3.5 and on samsung s5 mini i've strange behavior.
It has android 6.0.1. I've tested on other device (phone and tablet) with different version of android (4.4, 5.1, 6.0.1) and it works without problems.
The first thing is that when a page with a google maps is loaded it shows a section with a series of blacks dot like in the images:

[image]

The second is in the next page( tested even removing the page of the map), when i click on a select with dynamic content got with Http get function.
Insted of the options it shows strange content like in the next image

[image]

The code for the select:

```
<ion-item style="background-color:transparent;" text-wrap>
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="sceltamarca" (ionChange)="changeMarca($event)" >
  <ion-option selected value="" disabled style="font-size:10px;">Seleziona marca</ion-option>
  <ion-option *ngFor="let marca of marche" [value]="marca.marca"  >{{marca.marca}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

And the the code to add option:

```
this.http.get('link').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
this.marche = data;
loading.dismiss();
},
err => {
    console.log("Oops!");
    loading.dismiss();
});
```

The only device that gives me problem is Samsung s5 mini.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today on a S5 mini. I could resolve the issue by updating the Android System Webview: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview

For some reason it was't updating automatically.